# Comparar números en arreglos

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy trayendo varios numeros a distintos arreglos y quiero comparar si tiene elementos a comparar con otros 2

por ejemplo

tengo `[10, 12, 13, 14, 17, 18]`

y quiero saber si tiene el `[14, 18]`

esto es lo que tengo por ahora pero el fallo es que estoy comparando 1 solo numero del arreglo 2 veces y eso inevitablemente fallará, ya que por ejemplo, 14 no puede ser igual a 14 y 18.

```
if (features.length) {
features.forEach(function (feature) {
    var prop = feature.properties;
    if (prop.precio > precioDesde && prop.precio < precioHasta) {
        if (($('#check_id_detalle_14').is(':checked')) || ($('#check_id_detalle_18').is(':checked')) ) {
            if(!prop.ids_detalles_cualitativos.empty){
                prop.ids_detalles_cualitativos.forEach(element=>{
                    if ((element == $('#check_id_detalle_18').val()) && element == $('#check_id_detalle_14').val()) {
                        //do something
                    }
                })
            }
        } else {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de recorrer `prop.ids_detalles_cualitativos` con un `forEach` se puede usar la función `includes()` para determinar si el arreglo contiene los valores:

```
if (features.length) {
    features.forEach(function (feature) {
        var prop = feature.properties;
        if (prop.precio > precioDesde && prop.precio < precioHasta) {
            if (($('#check_id_detalle_14').is(':checked')) || ($('#check_id_detalle_18').is(':checked')) ) {
                if(!prop.ids_detalles_cualitativos.empty){
                    
                    if(
                      // se usa la función includes() para buscar en el arreglo
                      prop.ids_detalles_cualitativos.includes($('#check_id_detalle_18').val()) && 
                      prop.ids_detalles_cualitativos.includes($('#check_id_detalle_14').val())
                      ){
    
                        // do something
                      }
                }
            } else {
                //do nothing
            }
        }
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usar [.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/some)

```js
const arr = [10, 12, 13, 14, 17, 18]

res = arr.some(e=> e == 14 || e == 18)

console.log(res);
```

y si deseas buscar dentro de otro arreglos puedes modificar la respuesta y usar [.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/includes)

```js
const arr = [10, 12, 13, 14, 17, 18]
const numerosBusqueda = [14,18]
const otroArr = [1,2,3]
const res = arr.some(e=> numerosBusqueda.includes(e))


console.log(res)

const res2 = otroArr.some(e=> numerosBusqueda.includes(e))
console.log(res2)
```

Comment: me permites anexar algo a tu respuesta?

Comment: si claro @JackNavaRow